# 403 Error when building local application for Azure with PHP

Tags: php, azure

I am trying to build a simple php app following the guide [here](http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/build-and-deploy-a-windows-azure-php-application).  I have setup the SDK for PHP and can build the project fine.  When I build the project however the page loads with a 403 error.  In the web.config file I have the following for the default document:

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
  <clear/>
    <add value="index.php" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

If I take out the clear/ line and rebuild the project the page loads with a 500 internal server error.

Any ideas what could be causing this?
Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

403 is a forbidden page error - you probably aren't allowed to use that `<clear/>` variable.

500 internal server error usually means an error in your scripting language was thrown causing the script to crash.

You can use online tools to check the syntax of your code to make sure it doesn't contain any errors.

Here's one:
http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: Alright well assuming I can't use the <clear/> variable. I still get the 500 error.  And there shouldn't be a problem with the code.  It's a simple phpinfo script.

Comment: So all it is, is this: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` ? @sirgawain

Comment: You are required to use <clear/> by IIS in order for the PHP files to be parsed properly. If you removing it there will be the 500 errors you saw previously. It seems more likely that there is a permissions issue somewhere. Try enabling RDP and checking your web permissions. Also check the IIS config http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/enable-remote-desktop